# Mysql combine two query results in to one based on common group by fields

Tags: mysql

I need to combine the results of

```
select max(mark), exam_seq, subject_seq from mark where section_seq = 1 
group by exam_seq, subject_seq;
```

and

```
select mark, exam_seq, subject_seq from mark where stu_seq = 1 
group by exam_seq, subject_seq;
```

in to one result set.

Both the queries will return the same number of results. First query gets the max mark for the given Class-Section group by Exams and Subjects; Second query gets the individual marks for a Student group by Exams and Subjects.

Based on other posted answers to similar queries, I tried

```
select max(mark), exam_seq, subject_seq from mark where section_seq = 1 
group by exam_seq, subject_seq 
union all
select mark, exam_seq, subject_seq from mark where stu_seq = 1 
group by exam_seq, subject_seq
```

but it produces the result one below the other.

What I need is a result with
4 columns: mark, max(mark), exam_seq, subject_seq.

'mark' from second query and 
'max(mark)' from first query

Please note that the where conditions of the two sqls are different (based on two different fields). Please suggest. Thanks.

Here is the sample data for 1 Class-Section, 2 Exams, 5 Subjects and 2 Students:

```
section_seq   exam_seq   subject_seq   stu_seq   mark
1             1          1             1         65
1             1          1             2         56
1             1          2             1         65
1             1          2             2         56
1             1          3             1         56
1             1          3             2         65
1             1          4             1         99
1             1          4             2         88
1             1          5             1         55
1             1          5             2         66
1             2          1             1         65
1             2          1             2         56
1             2          2             1         77
1             2          2             2         68
1             2          3             1         99
1             2          3             2          9
1             2          4             1         88
1             2          4             2         45
1             2          5             1         66
1             2          5             2         66
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you can join on your group bys, so you can acheive that with a subquery and `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT allMarks.mark, max(mark), exam_seq, subject_seq from mark 
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(mark) as mark
    FROM mark 
    WHERE stu_seq = 1 
    GROUP BY exam_seq, subject_seq
) allMarks
ON allMarks.exam_seq = mark.exam_seq 
AND allMarks.subject_seq= mark.subject_seq
WHERE mark.section_seq = 1 
GROUP BY mark.exam_seq, mark.subject_seq
```

If we had some sample data, we could advise on that and check the structure is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Have added Sample data below the query, hope it helps. Just tried the above query, says error encountered, but no error content in the console, so not sure whats happening.